# Strange output using RequireJS to optimize

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm trying to optimize a javascript module from the the terminal. This is the build file (in a file called build.js) I'm running it against:

```
({
    appDir: '.',
    baseUrl: '.',

    optimize: 'none',
    dir: '.',

    stubModules: ['cs'],

    paths: {
        'cs': 'cs',
        'coffee-script': 'coffee-script'
    },

    modules: [{
        name: 'main',
        exclude: ['coffee-script']
    }]
})
```

In the terminal, I'm running

```
r.js -o name=build out=main-built.js
```

And here is the resulting contents of main-build.js:

`({appDir:".",baseUrl:".",optimize:"none",dir:".",stubModules:["cs"],paths:{cs:"cs","coffee-script":"coffee-script"},modules:[{name:"main",exclude:["coffee-script"]}]}),define("build",function(){})`

I don't understand this output. Why is my module not getting outputted at all? Why is uglify.js being run when I specifically wrote optimize: 'none'? Why is r.js not throwing any errors when I run -o?

Answer (score 0):

"Name" is the name of your starter module. Which is in fact the same name as your build, so this might be why there is confusion...

```
build.js
({
    name: 'mymodule', // replace this by the name of your first module, the wrapper.
    appDir: '.',
    baseUrl: '.',

    optimize: 'none',
    dir: '.',

    stubModules: ['cs'],

    paths: {
        'cs': 'cs',
        'coffee-script': 'coffee-script'
    },

    modules: [{
        name: 'main',
        exclude: ['coffee-script']
    }]
})
```

Command line I use with node: `node r.js -o build.js`

I'm not a requireJS expert or anything, I just found these things that I think are mistakes. You can see r.js built a module named build at the end of the file.

Comment: If "mymodule" is the first module, then what is 'main' below? Is that the second module?

Comment: Ah right, I read too fast... But the command you are using overwrites the main prop of the build.js... And to have proof that build.js is not used, your file is uglyfied. Just call r.js -o -build.js without the name part, to point to your config file.